# JavaScript objects listening to changes in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I would like to have an array dynamically generated by keypress, then have different JavaScript objects listening to changes in that array. For example, in games, pressing LEFT/RIGHT/UP/DOWN would store those 4 values in the array, which can be executed by different objects listening in to that array.

Is this a good approach? And if it is, how to go about setting up listeners to that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not looking into using a simple Array, but your custom implementation that applies the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). <del>The other (bad) alternative would be to poll changes to the array with a timer, but that doesn't seem feasible for a game.</del>

Actually, since you're writing a game, I would assume that you'll have a game loop that runs on a timer. Each interested object could simply read from the array in each update cycle. There is probably no need to push real-time changes to these objects. Unless, of course, you can't afford to lose any key strokes -- in which case you could buffer the keys in a more complex structure than a simple Array.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up register functions for each keypress?

```
var keyArray = [];
function addkey(key) {
    arr.push(key);
    dispatch();
}
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    addkey(e.which);
})
function dispatch() {
    /* CODE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a messaging queue model.  Have a central MessageQueue that takes events and notifies listeners.  Objects that want to do something on certain key presses can register themselves as listeners with the queue, and will be notified when the thing they care about happens.

Let's say you have a predefined set of events "UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", and "RIGHT" events.

```
var MESSAGE_QUEUE = function() {

    var eventListeners = {
        UP: [],
        DOWN: [],
        LEFT: [],
        RIGHT: []
    };

    return {

        register: function(event, obj) {
            var listeners = eventListeners[event];
            if (listeners) {
                listeners.push(obj);
            }
        },

        fire: function(event) {
            var listeners = eventListeners[event] || [];
            for (var i=0; i<listeners.length; i++) {
                listeners[i].onEvent(event);
            }
        }
    };
}();
```

Then an object that wants to be notified on DOWN says:

```
MESSAGE_QUEUE.register("DOWN", this);
```

`this` would be expected to defined an `onEvent` function.  Then whatever fires key events:

```
element.onKeyPress = function(event) {
    // ... figure out if down was presses
    MESSAGE_QUEUE.fire("DOWN");
}
```

Something like that would be a clean solution.  Clearly this could be changed to suit whatever needs you have, such as a variable number of events, or more clear function names, such as `onDown`, `onUp`, etc., defined for each listener.

Comment: Where do I set the actual DOWN events after registering the object to the QUEUE for DOWN?

Comment: Are you able to modify my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonchen/Laem7/ ? Based on your register fire method?

Answer (score 0):

Check out JavaScriptMVC's observe:

https://github.com/jupiterjs/jquerymx/blob/master/lang/observe/observe.js

It does what you are looking for:

```
o = new Observe.List([])
o.bind('change', function(ev, attr, how , newValue, oldValue ){

})

o.push('hello')
```